# Trying to understand Auto Layout

Tags: xcode, ios6, autolayout

I'm trying to understand how to use Auto Layout but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to accomplish something like this using it. I have an iPad ViewController with two subview views. I'd like the layout to work like in this representation but I'm not clear on which values to set. particularly the relationship between the two subviews:

[image: Auto Layout Help]

Comment: Are you setting this up in IB or in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left view should be pinned to the superview's top, left and bottom edges (with your padding) It's right edge should be pinned to the right view's left edge.

The right view should be pinned to the superview's top, right and bottom edges (with your padding). It should have a width constraint with a constant value, which you would set to the appropriate number on rotation.

In IB, you'd create an outlet to the width constraint. In code, just assign it to a property as you create it.